# Multiple threads in iphone

Tags: objective-c

how to create multyple threads  in iphone(in single class)

please help me with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for `NSThread`, `NSOperationQueue`, and the various `performSelector...` methods defined for `NSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

[NSThread Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003746)

An example to run a child thread:

```
- (void)threadRun
{
  // One thread, one autorelease pool. as main thread's pool inside main.c
  NSAutoreleasePool *aPool = [[NSAuroreleasePool alloc] init];

  // do-job in thread here

  [aPool release];
}

- (void)performJobWithThread
{
    // Method 1:
    NSThread *aThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          selector:@selector(threadRun)
                                          object:nil];

    [aThread start];

    /// Release aThread at some point avoid memory leak.

    // Method 2:
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector:@selector(threadRun)
                             toTarget:self
                             withObject:nil];
}
```

Before using NSThread, it's better to read [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) first. It will tell you about memory management, communication with other thread, ..., etc.

NSOperation and NSOperationQueue are good to design multithread. But I am learning them now and I am unable to talk about them clearly.